# Clarification on Texture Units Per Program in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

According to Apple's documentation for OpenGL ES 2.0 limitations:
["You can use up to 8 textures in a fragment shader."](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html)

This doesn't seem remarkably specific, and so I had assumed that it meant, "you can reference a maximum of 8 texture units for each pass of your fragment shader."

So what I've been doing, is in a given pass of my fragment shader, I reference only one texture unit, starting at texture unit 0. The next pass, I reference unit 1. The next pass, unit 2, and so on. Based on my above assumption, this should work fine for up to `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS.`

However, it only seems to work up until unit 7, and break at anything >= unit 8.

Does it sound like this would cause me to hit the maximum texture units? Or am I missing something?

If I am indeed hitting the upper limit of allowable texture units in a fragment shader, I suppose what I'll do is hold a mutable array of programs, and at runtime build as many programs as I need for how many textures I've defined, and when I hit steps of the texture unit index that is a multiple of 8, switch to the appropriate program.

Does this sound reasonable, or am I missing something?

Comment: If each pass only uses one texture, then why not just bind a new texture after each pass? I'm confused why you think you need to keep incrementing the texture unit number.

Comment: Wonderful! Because my understanding was completely wrong. I assumed assigning a texture to a given unit incurred the cost of sending the texture data to opengl, so I wouldn't want to switch units once a texture was used. Now that I'm always using unit 0, that solved whatever problems I was having with > 8. I'm slowly climbing my way up the learning curve so thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the maximum number of texture units on a device via something like the following:

```
+ (GLint)maximumTextureUnitsForThisDevice;
{
    GLint maxTextureUnits; 
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &maxTextureUnits);
    return maxTextureUnits;
}
```

Running this on the most powerful device I have, the Retina iPad, I get a maximum of 8 texture units. This means that you won't be able to bind a texture to anything above `GL_TEXTURE7`, and limits the number of simultaneous textures you can feed into a shader to 8.

However, as Tim suggests in his comment, if you just need to access one texture at a time, there's nothing stopping you from just sequentially binding each texture to a single unit, processing it, and then binding the next texture to that same unit.

Comment: Thanks for that code snippet, that looks like it'll be useful for all the glGet's. So can I safely assume that the number of textures I can use to draw one frame, as long as I never reference more than 8 textures in one fragment shader pass, is only limited by the memory constraints of the device that I'm on? If I've got this right, things might start making sense.

Comment: @jankins - Yes, if you're doing the rendering in multiple steps. The texture unit limit just impacts your ability to feed in multiple textures to a single render pass.